# No message body reader has been found for class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, resteasy

I have written a rest service to upload the file. I am using the rest easy for file upload. Also to mention I have tried all the solutions which i have found on SO for the related questions. But it does not work for me.
Below is my endpoint definition.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/ckeditorUpload")
public String uploadCkEditorFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream    uploadedInputStream,
@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData);
```

Below is the rest easy dependency in my pom.xml

```
            <!-- JAXB provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Multipart support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

Below is the error when i invoke this endpoint.

```
Jan 04, 2017 1:31:02 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils  logMessageHandlerProblem
SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class   com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, ContentType:   multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynN0AeoPCBbeHw7OC
Jan 04, 2017 1:31:02 PM  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media  Type
 at  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1313)
at  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:824)
at  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:787)
at  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterc eptor.java:212)
at  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterce ptor.java:77)
at  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.jav a:308)
at  org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserv er.java:121)
at  org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestina tion.java:251)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:107)
at com.moya.api.security.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:27)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at com.moya.api.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:350)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is weird: Jersey != CXF != resteasy.

Comment: @Michael-O yeah i agree, but how can i resolve it. Am i missing any dependency or wrong dependencies included ?

Comment: Can you include the complete pom.xml and web.xml ?

Comment: File upload with RESTEasy Multipart Dependency is done here: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/ also some deeper explanation you can find here https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Multipart.html

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to say what's wrong with code which you have provided but this code below works:

pom.xml

```
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>JAXRS-RESTEasy</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
            </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

RESTEasyFileUploadService.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.InputPart;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput;

@Path("/files")
public class RESTEasyFileUploadService {

     private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://path/where_to_store";

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {

        String fileName = "";

        Map<String, List<InputPart>> formParts = input.getFormDataMap();

        List<InputPart> inPart = formParts.get("file");

        for (InputPart inputPart : inPart) {

             try {

                // Retrieve headers, read the Content-Disposition header to obtain the original name of the file
                MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = inputPart.getHeaders();

                fileName = parseFileName(headers);
                // Handle the body of that part with an InputStream
                InputStream istream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class,null);

                fileName = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + fileName;

                saveFile(istream,fileName);

              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

            }

                String output = "File saved to server location : " + fileName;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    // Parse Content-Disposition header to get the original file name
    private String parseFileName(MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {

        String[] contentDispositionHeader = headers.getFirst("Content-Disposition").split(";");

        for (String name : contentDispositionHeader) {

            if ((name.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {

                String[] tmp = name.split("=");

                String fileName = tmp[1].trim().replaceAll("\"","");

                return fileName;

            }

        }

        return "randomName";

    }

    // save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,

        String serverLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```